# How to embed 3rd party widgets on Blogger

Tags: javascript, widget, blogger

As a webmaster, how can I allow Blogger users to embed my content on their blogs?

I tried the following solution - simple button redirecting to:

`https://www.blogger.com/blog-this.g?u=[ MY URL ]&amp;t=[ MY WIDGET CODE ]`

with  tag inside `[ MY WIDGET CODE ]`.

I encountered two problems:

- the `<script>` tag seems to be erased automatically from proposed post content
- even if user copies and pastes the script, it only works after publication - so user is unable to see how is it going to look like in the preview

Thanks in advance for any tips :)

Note: I know it is probably a security issue, but if blogger is able to post content with scripts then why isn't he able  to preview them?

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that script tags  are erased then you can make a js file and host it on google drive or any other servers you like and link this js to your blog template. I used this approach for third party plugins like codehighlighter and it works. You can see http://a2znotes.blogspot.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, this is not the problem I have. My goal is not to embed something on my own blog, but to allow all Blogger users to embed content from my website.

Comment: In that case you can make use of blogger feeds. It provides facility to include feeds from other blogs.https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/97933?hl=en

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I do not have a blog on Blogger. I have entirely different website that allows users to embed my content on their websites/blogs. Think YouTube and their embed player.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know *Blogger* but if I'm not mistaken they can add javascripts to their templates, then should be relatively easy to add content from other domains, add your script or just use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

sources:

- [Add jQuery to Your Blogger and Blogspot Template Code](http://bloggercando.blogspot.it/2014/05/add-jquery-to-your-blogger-and-blogspot.html)

**edit**

- [How to Add a Widget to Blogger](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Widget-to-Blogger)

  see #5: Add a custom widget to Blogger using the HTML and JavaScript widget

> The HTML and JavaScript widget within Blogger is a blank widget that allows you to add or paste **third-party functionality** or other code to your blog. The HTML and JavaScript widget can be found by clicking on "Add a Gadget" from the Blogger Layout screen

May be widgets work on preview.

Comment: Yes, Blogger users can add JS to their templates or posts. The problem is that JS does not execute in the posting preview.

Comment: @dev9 I may be wrong but probably they don't let you customize the *admin backend* because would allow unrecoverable situations, still is weird that they allow for `script` but then are not seen in the preview, you should check with you users for errors in the javascript console. Also, passing the script as a url argument is something you don't want to do, that would allow anyone to inject scripts, the way to go are remote `script` in the html or `jsonp`, or you may take a look to `iframe`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
<object data=http://xyz.blogspot.com/atom.xml width=”600″ height=”400″>
<embed src=http://xyz.blogspot.com/atom.xml width=”600″ height=”400″> </embed>
Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
```

This may help you.
Source: http://lowendmac.com/2006/embed-a-blogger-feed-in-your-web-page/

Comment: No, this is not what I wanted. I want to enable Blogger users to embed MY content, from my EXTERNAL website.

Comment: What you can do is use this code to create your embed code which you can give to users through your website.